# Add a $hint to rmongodb query

Tags: r, rmongodb

Does anyone know how to add a [`hint`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) argument to a mongo query when using the `rmongodb` package? Note: `hint` is now deprecated.

Currently I'm using the `mongo.find.all` query for it's simplicity rather than separate `cursor`, `buffer` commands.

```
mongo.find.all(mongo = mongo, 
               ns = "ops.weather", 
               query = "{\"where.zip_code\":\"60603\", \"what.currently.time\":{\"$gte\":1430936418}}",
               sort = mongo.bson.empty(), 
               fields = list(what.currently.time = 1L,
                             what.currently.precipIntensity = 1L,
                             what.currently.temperature = 1L,
                             what.currently.windSpeed = 1L,
                             what.currently.windBearing = 1L,
                             where.zip_code = 1L,
                             where.latitude = 1L,
                             where.longitude = 1L,
                             what.observation_type = 1L),
               limit = 0L,
               skip = 0L,
               options = 0L,
               data.frame = TRUE)
```

In mongo the query would look something like this, without all the fields in the full example above:

```
db.weather.find({"where.zip_code" : "60603","what.currently.time" : {"$gte" : 1430936418}}).hint("where.zip_code_1_what.currently.time_1")
```

The hint clearly improves query performance when used in Mongo, so it would be useful to implement in the ongoing R process.

Current sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmongodb_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.1      rstudioapi_0.3.1 Rcpp_0.12.0      jsonlite_0.9.16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a [bit of research](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/), I found that you can supply the hint as a $hint argument to the query.
In mongodb it would look like this:

```
db.weather.find( {$query: {...}, $hint: {"where": 1, ...}})
```

And you can do the same in rmongodb.
Change you query to something like this:

```
query = 
  "{\"$query\":
     {\"where.zip_code\":\"60603\", \"what.currently.time\":{\"$gte\":1430936418}},
    \"$hint\":
      \"where.zip_code_1_what.currently.time_1\"}"
```

I tested this and it worked on my test dataset without errors. Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Are you missing a comma at the end of the where statements `\"what.currently.time\":\"$gte\":1430936418}` should be `\"what.currently.time\":\"$gte\":1430936418},`?

Comment: In any event, two of us couldn't get this to work with commas, without commas, and with curly braces around the `$gte` part, e.g. `\"what.currently.time\":{\"$gte\":1430936418}}`.  I also tried escaping the quotes rather than using single quotes on the outside.

Comment: I did see that help earlier though, and I agree that looks like the way to go.  I arrived at the same syntax that you're using, and it looks like it should work.  Not sure what's wrong... I added `sessionInfo()` to my question. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Also, this is the error:
`Error in mongo.bson.from.JSON(arg) : 
  Not a valid JSON content: {"$query":{"whe...`

Comment: Actually, this works: `{"$query":{"where.zip_code":"60603"},"$hint":{"where.zip_code":1,"what.currently.time":1}}`, I'm working on getting the `gte` part back into the query.

Comment: Hi @geneorama , Sorry for not getting back to you earlier, have been quite busy recently... You were right and I did make a typo in the post. This should be corrected now. If you can provide some reproducible example for this, then I'd happy to look into this again.

Comment: This works, thanks!  (Although it's long enough that I can't remember what I ended up doing previously). Thanks for pointing out the different `$hint` syntax in the first place, that was key (pun not intended).